# How to prove that: $(\frac{1}{6}S_{tp})^3 \geq \sqrt{3}V^2$ for a tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry

In a tetrahedron ,prove that:
$$(\frac{1}{6}S_{tp})^3 \geq \sqrt{3}V^2$$
$S_{tp}$ is total area of four triangle of that tetrahedron.
V is volume of that tetrahedron 
 have no idea how to do this, can this be proved with simple geometry?

Comment: Is it a regular tetrahedron?

Comment: @mrprottolo it is any trtrahedron